# are there alternate ways to download pdfs from the internet without them being corrupted?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I have written code for a web scraper program that is as follows (in python) -

```
import requests, bs4  #you probably need to install requests and bs4, just go online and type beautiful soup 4 installation and requests installation


link_list = []
res = requests.get('https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=0&q=traffic+light+reinforcement+learning&hl=en&as_sdt=1,5&as_ylo=2019&as_vis=1')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if('pdf' in link.get('href')):
        link_list.append(link.get('href'))

for x in range(1,100):
    i = str(x*10)
    url = f'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start={i}&q=traffic+light+reinforcement+learning&hl=en&as_sdt=1,5&as_ylo=2019&as_vis=1'
    res_2 = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res_2.text, 'html.parser')
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        if('pdf' in link.get('href')):
           link_list.append(link.get('href'))


if(link_list):
    for x in range(0,len(link_list)):
        res_3 = requests.get(link_list[x])
        with open(f'/Users/atharvanaik/Desktop/Cursed/{x}.pdf', 'wb') as f: #parameter 1 of the open function is set to a file path that is available only on my computer
            f.write(res_3.content)
        print(x)                                         #Set it to something that is accessible on your computer. 
else:                                                                       #Your final path should be - 
    print('sorry, unavailable')                                             #Something\something\something\{x}.pdf
                                                                        #Do not change the last part !
```

For context, I am trying to bulk download pdfs from a google scholar search, instead of doing it manually.

I manage to download a vast majority of the pdfs, but some of the pdfs, when I tried opening them, gave me this message -

"It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognise."

As seen in the above code, I am using requests to download the content and write to the file. Is there a way to work around this ?

Comment: Try opening the file with Adobe Reader.  Does that work?

Comment: I ran the same program on windows and it didn't work, so it isn't a problem with the os. On the above commenters suggestion I also tried opening it with adobe reader and it didn't change much.